# Who is "you" in Genesis 3:15 according to the Calvinist?

Tags: genesis, reformed-theology

I have a "connected" question before in [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/61503/is-there-any-denomination-which-think-that-the-serpent-at-the-beginning-of-his?noredirect=1#comment167437_61503). And I think I made a mistake to ask a question like that directly.

So, I will start here first :

> Genesis 3:15
>  I will put enmity between **you** and the woman, and between
>   your offspring and her offspring; he shall bruise your head, and **you**
>   shall bruise his heel.

Who is "you" there ? Who did God talk to ? was God addressing reptile?

Comment: In light of Genesis 3:14, which begins  "The Lord God said to the serpent", is there any reason to believe that "you" does *not* refer to the serpent?

Comment: You mean God talk to that talking male snake which the most cunning of all the wild animals that the LORD God had made, Matt ?

Comment: Generally if someone is talking to someone else ("God said **to** the serpent") and one says "you", one is referring to the person/being/entity spoken to. So, yes.

Comment: Oke. So according to the Calvinist, the "you" in the verse is a male snake. Would you please put your comment in the answer box, Matt ? Thank you.

Comment: Clarify for us if you are asking if God was addressing a reptile? I think all denominations accept that the verse is directed to the spirit creature who deceived the woman

Comment: @Kris, I've edited the question. But from Matt Gutting's answer "So, yes" ---> it seems that the answer is _"Yes, God was addressing a reptile"_ which is maybe those animals (plural) are not a reptile kind yet when God talk to that reptile.

Answer (score 4):

**It was Satan**

> ”I acknowledge, indeed, that from this place alone nothing more can be collected than that men were deceived by the serpent. But **the testimonies of Scripture are sufficiently numerous, in which it is plainly asserted that the serpent was only the mouth of the devil**; for not the serpent but the devil is   declared to be the father of lies,' the fabricator of imposture, and   the author of death. The question, however, is not yet solved, why   Moses has kept back the name of Satan. I willingly subscribe to the   opinion of those who maintain that the Holy Spirit then purposely used   obscure figures, because it was fitting that full and clear light   should be reserved for the kingdom of Christ. In the meantime, the   prophets prove that they were well acquainted with the meaning of Moses, when, in different places, they cast the blame of our ruin upon  the devil. (Calvin, John. *The Complete Biblical Commentary Collection of John Calvin*. Kindle location 2840)”.

This view is consistent among Calvinists.

Comment: That’s a good find .  Perhaps bold the most important sentence?   And a bit more of your own words to flesh out the answer.

Comment: I tried. It’s so very painful doing this from a smartphone.