# According to Genesis 3:1, what could be God's necessity to create serpent(intelligence) to act aginst self

Tags: original-sin

According to Genesis 3:1, God created the serpent to be crafty and gave the serpent the ability to use the given intelligence.  That means there should not be the disobedient intelligence that will act against God: **how is it possible that serpent(intelligence) could act against God's self?**

Comment: ... _and the people spake against God ... and the Lord sent fiery serpents ... and they bit the people ..._ Numbers 21:5,6.

Comment: For the purposes of this site asking "Why did God..."  is almost always off topic, unless you prefix it with "according to X".  You can think that X is the source of ultimate truth, but you need to include X or else the question is answerable only by God.

Comment: people who are not eager to know the truth are seeking truth and proclaiming to be knowing the truth

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/61503/23657.  This related question and it’s answers may interest you

Answer (score 1):

Crafty is not necessarily bad.

> Behold, I send you forth as sheep in the midst of wolves: be ye therefore wise as serpents, and harmless as doves. Matthew 10:16 (KJV)

It is the use of God-given talents against God's will that makes it sin.

God also has perfect foreknowledge, so He did know exactly what would occur.

Comment: so god knew that he is about to introduce sin to the world

Comment: why god permits to use his power against him i think god wants a fighter for him to fight with

Comment: and comments are blocked because they can not handle truth but rely on self definition of their own truth